# MySQL проверка на два дубликата при записи

Tags: mysql, python

Есть таблица состоит из следующих столбцов: party_name, **party_id**, party, **party2_id**, val1, val2

Необходимо что бы при записи проверялись два значения **party_id** и **party2_id** если они уже существуют (именно два в одной строке БД) при попытки записи, то необходимо перезаписать "обновить" данные в этой строке.  По отдельности же party_id и party2_id могут повторятся бесчисленное количество раз, но вместе в одной строке могут встречаться лишь раз, но при этом может быть вариант когда party_id меняется местами с party2_id например:

Строка №1 БД **party_id** = 1 **party2_id** = 2

Строка №2 БД **party_id** = 2 **party2_id** = 1

В MySQL я полный новичек, до этого (не помню как) делал через phpmyadmin на одном из столбцов свойство "уникальный" - и это не позволяло мне записывать дубликаты в столбец- нужно ли делать эти же действия, или это нужно решать через код запроса к базе?

Код запроса:

```
query =(""INSERT INTO "" + ""allbase ""+""(party_name, party_id, party, party2_id, val1, val2) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE party_name=VALUES(party_name), party_id=VALUES(party_id), party=VALUES(party), val1=VALUES(val1), val2=VALUES(val2)"")
```

Comment: Готово! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запрос у вас правильный, он вставит новую запись если получится и обновит существующую строку, если вставляемая запись нарушит какое либо ограничение уникальности.

Ограничение уникальности - это либо первичный ключ (primary key), либо уникальный индекс (unique index). В одно ограничение должны войти обе колонки. Исходя из этого, если в таблице нет первичного ключа, либо вы считаете, что он не помешает вам правильно вставлять/обновлять то добавьте уникальный индекс:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX allbase_ind1 on allbase(party_id,party2_id);
```

В вашем случае два поля id вместе взятые вполне подходят под определение первичного ключа т.е. "уникально идентифицируют запись", в таком случае можно при создании таблицы (или позже) объявить первичный ключ на основе этих двух колонок:

```
create table allbase(party_id int not null ,
                     party2_id int not null,
                     ... прочие колонки..  ,
                     primary key(party_id,party2_id)
                    );
```

Comment: Спасибо! Первый вариант идеально подошел!